# Make UILabel show "No results" instead of "nan"

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

I have a small app, where user can make some calculations and solve equations. For example, if in a square equation discriminant is less than zero, the x1 and x2 values are "nan", so when I assign x1 and x2 values to UILabels they show "nan" as well. Writing a lot of if's like

```
if(D<0) [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"No solutions"]];
```

Doesn't help-there are too many cases. I want to check if after

```
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", x]];
```

label's value is "nan", the label's value will be set to @"No solutions".

Doing simple

```
if(label==@"nan") {
 //code
}
```

doesn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your following code block:

```
if(label==@"nan") {
 //code
}
```

1. You are referring to `label` instead of `[label text]` (or `label.text` if you prefer dot notation).
2. In Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch, you need to do string comparisons using [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)'s [`isEqualToString`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:) method.

Instead, try:

```
if ([[label text] isEqualToString:@"nan"]) {
 // Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use isnan macros:

```
[label setText:(isnan(x) ? @"No solutions" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", x])];
```